# Using Extended TreeMap with Hazelcast TreeMap, Act as Hazelcast distributed Map.

Tags: java, dynamic, treemap, hazelcast

I have one my own extended TreeMap named MyTreeMap which is used to create TreeMap dynamically based on the DAO passed as parameter MyTreeMap. Also,
Hazelcast provides its own TreeMap which we can have by creating instance of the Hazelcast.
like instance = Hazelcast.getMap("HazelcastTreeMap");

How i can achieve my own treemap "MyTreeMap" act as the Hazelcast treemap, not losing any of the extended properties. possessing both fetures of  both TreeMaps.

Comment: Is there a TreeMap implementation in Hazelcast?

Comment: How to Retrive TreeMap from hazelcast Map/ Hazelcast API... ?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast 3 has introduced the SPI. Hazelcast has a lot of distributed data-structures and they all use a common lower level infrastructure. We have pulled up this infrastructure in user space and called it the SPI.

Using this SPI you can now create your own distributed data-structures like the TreeMap. But you can also make other distributed services, e.g. a distributed actors implementation. So you are not longer limited by what Hazelcast provided, but only by your own imagination :)

Comment: Currently we have implemented Hazelcast 2.5. but before making it live we are really worried about memory consumption with hazelcast . 
Previously for communication between JVM's we had Linux PIPE communication. Moreover is Hazelcast 3.0 is more optimized than 2.5?

Comment: Currently Hazelcast 3.x has not received a lot of attention to reduce resource consumption (cpu/memory/network). But this is going to change once the 3.2 is released (in a a few weeks). Focus will be shifting from features to performance/scalability. Hazelcast Enterprise will be receiving new features, but the community edition is going to be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We will look forward for the release of version 3.2.. 
and thanks for the nice book on Hazelcast.